# Product varieties with the constructible topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X\subseteq k^n$, $Y\subseteq k^m$ be two affine algebraic varieties. It is not difficult to find examples where the Zariski topology on the product variety $X\times Y\subseteq k^{n+m}$ is not the product topology of the Zariski topologies on $X$ and $Y$.

Recall that the constructible topology on a variety is the topology with a base of open sets given by the constructible sets.

Is it true that the constructible topology of $X\times Y$ above is the product topology of the constructible topologies on $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Have you checked the case $X=Y=\mathbb{A}^1$?

Comment: Well... I think this is a trivial question, since points are closed (and so constructible) in the Zariski topology, then they are open in the constructible topology, which then coincides with the discrete topology... so the answer is "Yes, trivially."

Comment: This becomes less trivial if you consider prime spectrum instead of maximal spectrum (non necessarily closed points vs closed points).

Comment: @Cantlog: Of course for schemes it is less trivial... any guess for that case? For example when X and Y are ring spectra?

Comment: Take $X=Y=\mathbb A^1$ (over a field). Consider the open neighborhood $X\times X \setminus \Delta(X)$ (diagonal) of the generic point $\xi$ of $X\times X$. It can't contain a neighborhood of $\xi$ of the form $U\times V$ with $U, V$ constructible, for, $U, V$ must contain the generic point of $X$, hence contain a dense open subset each $U_1, V_1$. But $U_1\cap V_1\ne\emptyset$, so $U_1\times V_1$ meets the diagonal. Contradiction. Conclusion: product top. $\ne $ constructible top.